# How is the center calculated in this Openlayers 3 example?

Tags: openlayers

I've seen the demo of auto tracking (when clicking simulate) http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/geolocation-orientation.html and tried to copy it.

and I want to modify the code and place the marker on different places on the screen (in the center for example).

I know the "magic" is done in this function :

```
var getCenterWithHeading = function (position, rotation, resolution) {
var size = map.getSize();
var height = size[1];

return [
    position[0] - Math.sin(rotation) * height * resolution * 1 / 4,
    position[1] + Math.cos(rotation) * height * resolution * 1 / 4
];
```

}

But I don't understand how to modify it so the marker will be in the center of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the marker position as center:

```
return [
    position[0],
    position[1]
];
```

Comment: But if I change the position than the location of the marker is not correct according to the GPS coordinates it record (the location on the map) , which means that the map itself is not moving to the correct place